# SQL: performantly find the percent overlap between two foreign key child tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, hash, hashset

Assume I have the following tables/fields:

```
CREATE TABLE tbl_projects (
  prjc_id int PRIMARY KEY
)

CREATE TABLE tbl_project_requirements (
  preq_prjc_id int -- Foreign key to tbl_projects
  preq_type_id int -- A standardized requirement category
)
```

Given a specific project, I would like to find other projects that have *nearly* similar **requirement categories**... or let's say at least a 75% overlap on their requirements.

I could do the following:

```
DECLARE @prjc_id int = 1

CREATE TABLE #project_reqs (type_id int)
INSERT INTO #project_reqs
SELECT preq_req_type_id
FROM tbl_project_requirements
WHERE preq_prjc_id = @prjc_id

SELECT prjc_id
FROM tbl_projects
  CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT CASE 
        WHEN COUNT(*) = 0 THEN 0.0
        ELSE COALESCE(SUM(CASE WHEN type_id = prjc_type_id THEN 1.0 ELSE 0.0 END), 0.0)
           / CONVERT(float, COUNT(*))
      END AS similarity
    FROM #project_reqs 
      FULL OUTER JOIN (
        SELECT prjc_type_id
        FROM tbl_project_requirements
        WHERE preq_prjc_id = prjc_id
      ) reqs ON preq_type_id = type_id
  ) reqs
WHERE prjc_id != @prjc_id
  AND similarity >= 0.75
```

In the above, I'm dividing the **matched** requirement categories by the total **distinct** requirement categories between each two projects to get the % overlap.

While this works, I sense code smells, and don't think this will scale very well. Is there any sort of method that exists to performantly calculate overlap of child records between two items? Maybe some sort of partial hash matching or...?

## Update

I think I found a performant solution:

```
DECLARE @prjc_id int = 1

CREATE TABLE #project_reqs (type_id int)
INSERT INTO #project_reqs
SELECT preq_req_type_id
FROM tbl_project_requirements
WHERE preq_prjc_id = @prjc_id

DECLARE @project_req_count float
SELECT @project_req_count = COUNT(*)
FROM #project_reqs

CREATE TABLE #projects (
  pj_prjc_id int,
  pj_func_count float,
  pj_func_common float
)

INSERT INTO #projects
SELECT preq_prjc_id,
  COUNT(*),
  COUNT(type_id)
FROM tbl_project_requirements
  LEFT OUTER JOIN #project_reqs
    ON preq_type_id = type_id
GROUP BY preq_prjc_id
HAVING COUNT(type_id) != 0

SELECT pj_prjc_id
FROM #projects
WHERE pj_func_common / (pj_func_count + @project_req_count - pj_func_common) >= 0.75

DROP TABLE #project_reqs
DROP TABLE #projects
```

Answer (score 1):

There is more elegant way to find common requirements.

```
;with proj as (
    select preq_prjc_id pr, count(preq_type_id) typeCnt
    from tbl_project_requirements
    group by preq_prjc_id
)
,crossProj as (
    select p1.pr proj1,p2.pr proj2, p1.typeCnt
    from proj p1
    cross join proj p2 --make Cartesian product
    where p1.pr <> p2.pr
)
,req as (
    select preq_type_id, cp.proj1, cp.proj2, cp.typeCnt
    from tbl_project_requirements pq
    inner join crossProj cp on pq.preq_prjc_id=cp.proj1
    intersect -- what is common
    select preq_type_id, cp.proj1, cp.proj2, cp.typeCnt
    from tbl_project_requirements pq
    inner join crossProj cp on pq.preq_prjc_id=cp.proj2
)
--calculate final result
select proj1, proj2,
count(preq_type_id) commonPreq, 
--percent of common requirements relative to proj1
count(preq_type_id) * 100.00 / typeCnt [percentage]
from req
group by proj1, proj2, typeCnt
having count(preq_type_id) * 100.00 / typeCnt >75
order by [percentage] desc
```

### Update

```
;with proj as (
    select preq_prjc_id pr, count(preq_type_id) typeCnt
    from tbl_project_requirements
    group by preq_prjc_id
)
,crossProj as (
    select p1.pr proj1,p2.pr proj2, p1.typeCnt
    from proj p1
    cross join proj p2 --make Cartesian product
    where p1.pr <> p2.pr
)
,req as (
    select preq_type_id, cp.proj1, cp.proj2
    from tbl_project_requirements pq
    inner join crossProj cp on pq.preq_prjc_id=cp.proj1
    intersect -- what is common
    select preq_type_id, cp.proj1, cp.proj2
    from tbl_project_requirements pq
    inner join crossProj cp on pq.preq_prjc_id=cp.proj2
)
--calculate final result
select proj1, proj2,
count(preq_type_id) commonPreq,
--percent of common requirements relative to proj1
count(preq_type_id) * 100.00 /(p1.typeCnt + p2.typeCnt - count(preq_type_id))  [percentage]
from req
inner join proj p1 on req.proj1=p1.pr
inner join proj p2 on req.proj2=p2.pr
group by proj1, proj2,p1.typeCnt, p2.typeCnt
having count(preq_type_id) * 100.00 /(p1.typeCnt + p2.typeCnt - count(preq_type_id)) >75
order by [percentage] desc
```

Comment: I'm having a difficult time wrapping my head around this strategy... however your comment "percent of common requirements relative to proj1" leads me to think that it's not a % of the total distinct requirements between *BOTH proj1 and proj2*

Comment: What do you mean by "BOTH proj1 and proj2"? For example, proj1 has 20 requirements and proj2 has 15 requirements, 12 requirements are common to both. I calculate `12 * 100.00 / 20`.

Comment: proj1 has 8 requirements not in proj2, proj2 has 3 requirements not in proj1, and 12 requirements are common to both... 12 / (12+8+3)

Comment: I think your strategy works, however it's getting the overlap score for the cartesian product... whereas, I only want to calculate one project's score against all others... I think I came up with performant solution w/ your help. See my update in the question

Comment: just add `where ` filter.  `crossProj as (select p1.pr proj1,p2.pr proj2, p1.typeCnt from proj p1 cross join proj p2 where p1.pr = 1 and p1.pr <> p2.pr`

Answer (score 0):

If you're only doing this for one project then you should already know the number of matches that are required for a 75% match (or at least you can calculate it easily and quickly) enough:

```
DECLARE @num_matches_required INT

SELECT @num_matches_required = CEILING(COUNT(*) * 0.75)
FROM
    tbl_Project_Requirements
WHERE
    preq_prjc_id = @preq_prjc_id

SELECT
    R2.preq_prjc_id    -- One reason not to use abbreviations... I have to think, "Is it proj? prj? prjc? prjct?"
FROM
    tbl_Project_Requirements R1
INNER JOIN tbl_Project_Requirements R2 ON
    R2.preq_type_id = R1.preq_type_id AND
    R2.preq_prjc_id <> @preq_prjc_id
WHERE
    R1.preq_prjc_id = @preq_prjc_id
GROUP BY
    R2.preq_prjc_id
HAVING
    COUNT(*) >= @num_matches_required
```

Comment: Doesn't this example ignore requirements that are in R2, but not in R1? I'd like to get the % overlap between all of the distinct requirements both in R1 and R2 (hence my FULL OUTER JOIN)

Comment: Ahh, so it's a % of the total distinct reqs, not the reqs of the project in question? Then correct, I don't think this method will work.